# How to make a hyperlink jump to a specified place on the same page?

Tags: html, anchor

Can someone please tell me how to make a hyperlink jump to a specified place on the same page.”

Eg. The reader clicks a link and is taken to the bottom of the same page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make the link jump to the element with a hash:

```css
#bottom{
  margin-top:1000px;
}
```

```html
<a href="#bottom">jump to bottom</a>
<div id="bottom">bottom</div>
```